# Média dos números de uma matriz em C

Tags: c, array, matemática

Preciso de criar um programa que me construa uma matriz e que me devolva a media dos seus números.

Já tenho a matriz construída mas não consigo fazer a média dos valores.

O código que já tenho:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int matriz [3][3] ={{0}}, i, j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("introduza numeros para a matriz nos lugares [%d][%d] \n", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\t");
    printf("estes sao os valores da matriz\n\n");
    printf("\t\t matriz ordenada");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("%6d", matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Obrigado Tiago pela edição da pergunta

Comment: O que essa impressão, teste de matriz ordenada te ma ver com o problema?

Comment: Nao, nao. isto é para construir a matriz o que queria agora era fazer a media dos valores da matriz

Comment: mas isso não está construindo a matriz.

Comment: Quando corro esse codigo e introduzo os numeros a matriz é construida

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Tem que percorrer toda a matriz e somar os números, daí é só dividir pelo número de elementos, que é a fórmula da média.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int matriz [3][3] = {{0}};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("introduza numeros para a matriz nos lugares [%d][%d] \n", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\testes sao os valores da matriz\n\n");
    printf("\t\t matriz ordenada");
    int soma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
           soma += matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("\nMédia: %d", soma / 9);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/o6WORg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qzjnmghq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Average.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: @DidiMaster veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.